# Object Detection API, TensorFlow and Keras compatibility issue

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, object-detection-api

I'm trying to follow this tutorial and I'm running into issue setting up the environment.

https://towardsdatascience.com/borderless-tables-detection-with-deep-learning-and-opencv-ebf568580fe2

The tutorial requires Python 3.7, TensorFlow 2.3 and https://github.com/philferriere/cocoapi.git#subdirectory=PythonAPI

After executing the following commands:

> protoc object_detection\protos*.proto — python_out=. copy
>
> object_detection\packages\tf2\setup.py .
>
> python setup.py install

it will install keras by itself then when I execute the following command:
python object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py

I'll get the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\models\keras_models\resnet_v1.py",
> line 28, in 
> from keras.applications import resnet  # pylint:
> disable=g-import-not-at-top
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
> During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24,
> in                                           from
> object_detection.builders import model_builder
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py",
> line 37, in 
> from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\meta_architectures\deepmac_meta_arch.py",
> line 20, in 
> from object_detection.models.keras_models import resnet_v1
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\models\keras_models\resnet_v1.py",
> line 30, in 
> from tf_keras.applications import resnet  # pylint:
> disable=g-import-not-at-top
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tf_keras'

I'm not good at debugging other people's work but I tried deleting the standalone keras version and sticking with tensorflow's integrated keras. Then I went into resnet_v1.py and changed

```
try:
  from keras.applications import resnet  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
except ImportError:
  from tf_keras.applications import resnet  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
```

to

```
try:
  from tensorflow.keras.applications import resnet  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
except ImportError:
  from tf_keras.applications import resnet  # pylint: disable=g-import-not-at-top
```

Now I'm getting the following error:

> (borderlessTable) C:\Users\user\Desktop\Symfony\models\research>python
> object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py
> 2024-01-14 18:05:20.530858: W
> tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could
> not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll
> not found
> 2024-01-14 18:05:20.531083: I
> tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart
> dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "object_detection\builders\model_builder_tf2_test.py", line 24,
> in                                           from
> object_detection.builders import model_builder
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\builders\model_builder.py",
> line 37, in 
> from object_detection.meta_architectures import deepmac_meta_arch
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\object_detection-0.1-py3.7.egg\object_detection\meta_architectures\deepmac_meta_arch.py",
> line 28, in 
> import tensorflow_io as tfio  # pylint:disable=g-import-not-at-top
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io-0.31.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow_io_*init*_.py",
> line 17, in 
> from tensorflow_io.python.api import *  # pylint:
> disable=wildcard-import
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io-0.31.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow_io\python\api_*init*_.py",
> line 19, in 
> from tensorflow_io.python.ops.io_dataset import IODataset
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io-0.31.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow_io\python\ops_*init*_.py",
> line 96, in 
> plugin_ops = *load_library("libtensorflow_io_plugins.so", "fs")
>
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io-0.31.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow_io\python\ops_*init**.py",
> line 64, in *load_library
>
> l = load_fn(f)
>
> File
> "C:\Users\user.conda\envs\borderlessTable\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_io-0.31.0-py3.7-win-amd64.egg\tensorflow_io\python\ops_*init**.py",
> line 56, in 
> load_fn = lambda f: tf.experimental.register_filesystem_plugin(f) is
> None                                           AttributeError: module
> 'tensorflow._api.v2.experimental' has no attribute
> 'register_filesystem_plugin'

How to resolve this?

Comment: Make sure you are working in a clean environment to avoid conflicts between different versions of packages.

Comment: Make sure you have the correct version of Tensorflow installed. As of Tensorflow 2.x, the keras module is integrated and you can import it directly from tensorflow.keras. And Kindly follow this step by step instructions mentioned in [link](https://github.com/sglvladi/TensorFlowObjectDetectionTutorial/blob/master/docs/source/install.rst#tensorflow-object-detection-api-installation) to install TensorFlow Object Detection API.